# Drrupal 7 theme_preprocess_node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to change the title and body before Drupal show the node content.

I could change and see the new title using my theme preprocess_node.
I could change but not see the new body in the page using the same my_theme_preprocess_node.

Using dpm I can see that the body is changed but in the page the body is the same.

How can I see the body change in the body page content?

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
if ($variables['title'] == "my node title") {
$variables['title'] = 'my new node title';
$variables['body'][0]['value'] = 'my new body content';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the hook_node_view_alter to modify your body field.

See [hook_node_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)